# Addition of web service access in servlet unrecognized/unresolved; seen as "type".

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I am trying to create a simple servlet (tomcat) that accesses a database, then a USDA web service. I've successfully deployed/tested the database connectivity. When I added the web service access, eclipse reports the problem: AwdbWebService_Service **cannot be resolved to a type**.
The hour is late... I just don't see why this won't resolve as a service instance.

The error is tripped by this line:

*AwdbWebService_Service lookup = new AwdbWebService_Service(wsURL,new  QName("http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService","AwdbWebService"));*

Here is the code:

```
 package localdomain.localhost;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.net.URL; //added for usda webservice

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 import javax.annotation.Resource;
 import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 import javax.xml.namespace.QName;       // added for usda webservice
 import usda.nrcs.wcc.awdbWebService.*;

 @WebServlet(value = "/MyServlet")
 public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

   // use this for usda reservoir station values later
   static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

   protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
   @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydb", lookup = "jdbc/mydb")
   private DataSource dataSource;



   @Override
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
      super.init(config);
      logger.info("Init");
      System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ".init");
  }



  protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<head><title>MyServlet</title></head>");
    writer.println("<body><h1>MyServlet</h1>");

    writer.println("<h2>DataSource</h2>");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        writer.println("Datasource: " + dataSource + "<br/><br/>");
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("select 1");
        while (rst.next()) {
            writer.println("Resultset result: " + rst.getString(1) + "<br/><br/>");
        }
        rst.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        writer.println("SUCCESS to access the datasource");

        // Now try accessing usda
        URL wsURL = new URL("http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?wsdl");

        AwdbWebService_Service lookup = new AwdbWebService_Service(wsURL,new QName("http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService","AwdbWebService"));
        m_webService = lookup.getAwdbWebServiceImplPort();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(writer);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    writer.println("</body></html>");

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please show the AwdbWebService_Service.java

Comment: I am attempting to make AwddbWebService_Service a reference to the package usda.nrcs.wcc.awdbWebService which I generated from a wsimport from the wsdl @ http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?WSDL -- so the package contains multiple methods/java  classes. My intent is to use m_webService to make the calls from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those following this thread:

The package statement at the start of the java classes I generated with wsimport begins with:

*package gov.usda.nrcs.wcc.awdbWebService*

My import statement however looked like this:
import usda.nrcs.wcc.awdbWebService.*;

In essence I placed the source @ the wrong level and defined the build config to point incorrectly for the package references in the java classes. I removed the build reference, moved the tree to begin pointing on the gov level. Now that there wasn't a mismatch, the unresolved type error vanished.